# Item field value not passing to model page in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I am selecting a value from select list field from PAGE-1, then clicking a button to open a model page (PAGE-2). Need to pass the select list field value from PAGE-1 to model page, but the value is not passing to model page. sometime the item field in model page (PAGE-2) displaying null and sometime displaying previous selected value.

```
PAGE-1->select List Item Field
      ->Button->Redirect to Model page no (PAGE-2)->Link Builder (p1_select_list_item = &p2_item.)
```

Note: using oracle apex version 19.1

Answer (score 0):

Hm, are you sure you did it right? This:

> Link Builder (`p1_select_list_item = &p2_item.`)

should actually be vice versa as you're opening Page 2 and should pass value from Page 1 to Page 2, so try `p2_item = &p1_select_list_item.` instead.

---

On the other hand, if that was just a typo, then cause of your problem might be the fact that `P1_SELECT_LIST_ITEM`'s value isn't in session state.

A simple workaround is to

- let the button **submit** the page
- create a **branch**

  - ... which will then redirect to Page 2
  - ... and pass value to `P2_ITEM`

Comment: Thank you.. That was actually typo (p2_item = &p1_select_list_item). Its now working as per your solution. But 1 more challenge if there are display only fields and hidden fields (can handle Value Protected=NO) while submit.